# How to approach a professor for an independent study course?

Tags: independent-study

I'm a first year masters student and I want to do an independent study with a professor, because I find some of the first year graduate level courses too easy (I got permission from my concentration advisor to do an independent study). How do I decide the topic for the independent study with the professor? If I just pick a topic I want to study, I doubt the professor would want to do it. Should I ask the professor if she has any topics she wants to do an independent study on?

Comment: _If I just pick a topic I want to study, I doubt the professor would want to do it._ Why?  And if that's the case, why do you want to do an independent study with that particular professor?  (From the question I assume you have a particular professor in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in mathematics, beginning grad students often cannot make *informed* choices about worthwhile directions of study, and there can be advantages to getting more-expert opinion. This is not at all to say that you should not follow your own curiosity and intellectual impulses! But only that you should *also* be open to expert advice. So you might best view arranging your independent/directed study as an enterprise whose goals can be *negotiated*, hopefully with all parties thinking of your best (long-term?) interests.